# How to invert the anchoring inside a `<div>` to the bottom instead of the top?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm building a chat application and need the messages to anchor to the bottom of the message index and grow up rather than hanging from the top of the message index. I'm building this in react, so the following code is actually JSX.

Message index:

```
        <div className="chat-message-index">
         {this.state.activeChannel.messages.map(function(message{
           return <Message key={message.sid} message={message} />;
            })}
        </div>
```

Messages (rendered within the index):

```
<div className="chat-message">
  <b className="name">{this.state.author}</b><br/>
  <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.message.body}} />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.chat-message-index {
  height: calc(~"100vh - 250px");
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
  display: list-item;
}

.chat-message {
  position:relative;
  padding:10px;
  margin:22px 45px 22px 20px;
  color:#fff;
  background:#43464b;
  background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#aeb5ba), to(#43464b));
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(#aeb5ba, #43464b);
  background:-o-linear-gradient(#aeb5ba, #43464b);
  background:linear-gradient(#aeb5ba, #43464b);
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

I have tried every CSS trick I can think of, every idea I've found through Googling and here on SO, and I just can't find anything. The closest I've gotten is by using `transform:rotate(180deg);` on both the message index and the messages, but that inverts the scrolling and causes a scroll bar to appear on the left side of the index, which doesn't work. I can probably make this approach work, but it feels very hacky and my gut feeling is it will cause headaches down the road...

Does anybody know how to simply invert the anchoring for a `<div>`? All I want is for the first message to display at the bottom of the message index `<div>` and then each additional message to stack on top of the `<div>`'s that came before.

Comment: probably a javascript solution where you reverse the order of divs, You cannot reverse order with CSS alone AFAIK

Comment: Or instead of appending new messages you can prepend them, so they will be "above" the last message

Comment: @Aziz Yes...you can. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
.chatbox {
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  text-align: center;
}
.message {
  background: lightgreen;
  margin-bottom: .25em;
  padding: .25em 0 0 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatbox">
  <div class="message">MESSAGE 1</div>
  <div class="message">MESSAGE 2</div>
  <div class="message">MESSAGE 3</div>
  <div class="message">MESSAGE 4</div>
  <div class="message">MESSAGE 5</div>
  <div class="message">MESSAGE 6</div>
  <div class="message">MESSAGE 7</div>
  <div class="message">MESSAGE 8</div>
  <div class="message">MESSAGE 9</div>
  <div class="message">MESSAGE 10</div>
  <div class="message">MESSAGE 11</div>
  <div class="message">MESSAGE 12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what sorcery is this? BTW what about that whitespace at the top

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Aziz Is part of the chatbox, it has  height: 500px;

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can try:

1. [css] Use `flexbox` with `flex-direction: column-reverse`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction for more details. Their [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction#Live_Sample) does exactly what you want.
2. [js] sort your messages list so that the top-most item is at index 0 and the oldest item is at index `last`. This is less clean than the css solution above though.